# Detect which button was pressed first?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to write a simple program that detects which of my 2 buttons was pressed first. Although I think the code is written correctly, the output doesn't seem to be anything what I would expect.

I am using a simple array of integers to record the "placements" of which button was pressed first and second, as you can see below.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
}

int location = 0;
int placement[2] = {99, 99}; 

bool pressed = false;

void loop() {

  if (digitalRead(5) == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("RESET BUTTON IS PRESSED");
    placement[0] = 99;
    placement[1] = 99;
    pressed = false;
    location = 0;
  }

  if (digitalRead(7) == HIGH)
  {
    if (placement[location] == 99)
    {
      placement[location] = 7;
      location++;
      pressed = true;
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH)
  {
    if (placement[location] == 99)
    {
      placement[location] = 8;
      location++;
      pressed = true;
    }
  }

  if (pressed == true)
  {
    String text = String(location) + ". place: button n. " +     String(placement[location]);
    Serial.println(text);
    pressed = false;
  }

}
```

What I expect from the program after pushing my 2 buttons nearly at the same time is a simple output in the console:

1. place = button n. 8
2. place = button n. 7

If only one button is pressed, then I only expect one line printed in the console. However, even if I only press one button, the console prints 2 lines like this:

[image]

Does anyone know, what could be causing this? This is my first time programming in this "cyclic" way, so if this is some kind of a rookie mistake, I am truly sorry. Thanks to anyone who answers and who takes their time to read this, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String(placement[location])` is printing after you've already increased location by one.  So you are getting `placement[1]` and `placement[2]` (which is outside of the bounds of the array), thus the 99 and 0 showing up.

Comment: Oh my god, how could have I not see this? Thank you so much! I am very embarrassed now :S Thank you a lot!